# MVC external url file path equivalent to Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am exploring image conversion using

```
return base.File(path, "image/png");
```

I use

```
string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/media/148110/image-name.png");
```

The above method requires a relative file path. Is it possible to do the same thing with an absolute file path point at an external server?

Comment: Shouldn't the external path just  be a path? Server.mapPath tries to map the path to your application(using applications base assembly location as reference), then wouldn't your answer be as simple as, just call the external image URL without using any complicated c#.

Comment: You'd think... but unfortunately it return an error saying the URL is invalid. I've still got a lot to learn but this leads me to believe that the method is completely different, not just the syntax.I imagine that it has something to do with the image storage. If pointed at an external URL, the server has to download and process the image before it can convert it, I guess.... Where as the MapPath method relies on the image already existing on the server

Comment: You probably have to retrieve the image using FTP or similar. See [How to: Download files with FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-download-files-with-ftp).

Comment: If you want to download the image, try HttpCLient and use downloadFile or DownloadFileAsync, then process the image from the downloaded file.